# set state Badge appbar - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to increment the app bar icon by making a custom app bar. But I can't update the value with setState. I tried to update the value by the setAppBarValue function, but it didn't work.

```
MyAppBar.of(context)?.setAppBarValue(_counter);
```

```dart
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _incrementCounter();
          MyAppBar.of(context)?.setAppBarValue(_counter);
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  MyAppBar() : super();

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(60);
  @override
  _MyAppBarState createState() => _MyAppBarState();

  static _MyAppBarState? of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppBarState>();
}

class _MyAppBarState extends State<MyAppBar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _appBarValue = 0;

  setAppBarValue(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _appBarValue = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
        title: const Text("teste"),
        actions: <Widget>[Center(child: _alertBadge(context))]);
  }

  Widget _alertBadge(BuildContext context) {
    return Badge(
      position: BadgePosition.topEnd(
        top: 0,
        end: 3,
      ),
      badgeStyle: BadgeStyle(
        badgeColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      badgeContent: Text(
        _appBarValue.toString(),
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      child:
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined), onPressed: () {}),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: easily achieve with using Getx.

Answer (score 0):

You Have to pass the increment variable value to the appbar widget like this:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar(
        appBarValue: _counter,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _incrementCounter();
          // MyAppBar.of(context)?.setAppBarValue(_counter);
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And use that value in your app bar widget:

```
class MyAppBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const MyAppBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.appBarValue,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int appBarValue;

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(60);
  @override
  _MyAppBarState createState() => _MyAppBarState();

  static _MyAppBarState? of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppBarState>();
}

class _MyAppBarState extends State<MyAppBar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  // int _appBarValue = 0;
  //
  // setAppBarValue(int value) {
  //   setState(() {
  //     _appBarValue = value;
  //   });
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
        title: const Text("teste"),
        actions: <Widget>[Center(child: _alertBadge(context))]);
  }

  Widget _alertBadge(BuildContext context) {
    return Badge(
      position: BadgePosition.topEnd(
        top: 0,
        end: 3,
      ),
      badgeStyle: BadgeStyle(
        badgeColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      badgeContent: Text(
        widget.appBarValue.toString(),
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      child:
      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined), onPressed: () {}),
    );
  }
}
```